# terraform dynamically get key names of inner maps

Tags: terraform

I have a map as below

```
{
    "prod": {
        "test1": "value1",
        "keytoget": "value2",
        "secretsomething": "value3",
    },
    "demo": {
        "somediffkey": "value1",
        "anotherdiffkey": "value2",
    }
}
```

In a terraform resource i was using for_each loop.
I would like to access the keys within say demo map for e.g "somediffkey".

But i might not know the key name and would want to dynamically access the key name similarly to how we access each.key which returns "demo" and "prod".

Wanted to see if something like below

```
resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "az-secret" {
#   count               = length(locals.environments)
  mount               = vault_mount.kvv2-azure.path
  for_each            = local.environments
  name                = each.key
  cas                 = 1
  delete_all_versions = true
  data_json = jsonencode(
    {
      (each.key) = each.value # here the json should have somediffkey = value1 and then anotherdiffkey = vaulue2
    }
  )
}
```

Basically the resource should have internal maps data as key value pair in the json
Is this possible? Request help on this.

Comment: "was using for_each loop." - what for_each loop?  What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin no error but  not expected result. We should have the internal map as key value in the resource. Basically is it possible to access internal map's key dynamically without knowing the name i.e i dont want to access the value as each.value["somediffkey"] cause "somediffkey" would be given as input and could be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `jsonencode` the `each.value` field:

```
resource "vault_kv_secret_v2" "az-secret" {
  mount               = vault_mount.kvv2-azure.path
  for_each            = local.environments
  name                = each.key
  cas                 = 1
  delete_all_versions = true
  data_json           = jsonencode(each.value)
}
```

Comment: Please remove the commented out part of your answer.